# Identificar se conjunto de coordenadas está dentro de um raio em Android

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Quero delimitar um raio a partir de uma coordenada central (o marcador vermelho na figura) e, a partir de um conjunto de coordenadas (os marcadores verdes), verificar se estas estão dentro da área delimitada por este raio.

- Como identificar, a partir de um conjunto de coordenadas (latitude e longitude), se **estas** ou **quais delas** estão dentro de um determinado raio usado como referência?
- É possível **configurar o tamanho** desse raio?

Preciso de uma exemplo real, um projeto de exemplo em Android.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A biblioteca `gmaps.gs` oferece `geofencing`, que é o nome deste tipo de prática. http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geofences.html

Comment: @OnoSendai, parece-me que a biblioteca é para JavaScript. Preciso desse recurso no Android.

Comment: A lib é operacional via Chrome for Android. Talvez você queira dizer um recurso para aplicações nativas (acabei de perceber a tag android API) - neste caso: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Isso mesmo, @OnoSendai, aplicações nativas. Vou dar uma olhada no link. Obrigadão!

Comment: Deve ter algo pronto pra isso já, mas no pior dos casos você pode simplesmente usar um cálculo de distância: `distancia = sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy )` sendo que dx e dy são as diferenças entre o centro e a posição da pessoa. Notar que isto funciona para pequenas distâncias (poucos KM, e a uma certa distância dos polos), pois não leva em conta a esfericidade da terra.

Comment: Existe alguma base de dados que você armazena estes pontos? Se local ou de um servidor, você pode determinar isto diretamente em uma *query*.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, possuo esse conjunto de coordenadas armazenado, sim. Eu não preciso fazer uso do Geofance, como citou @OneSendai? Como seria essa abordagem?

Comment: @GeisonSantos mas estão armazenadas em qual banco de dados? *SQLite* no aparelho? *MySQL* no servidor? *SQLServer*? Outro?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, os dados estão armazenados numa base de dados MySQL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Como você disse, se o armazenamento está sendo feito em uma base de dados `MySQL` no servidor, imagino que você tenha uma chamada via *webservice* para buscar estes dados. Sendo assim, você pode determinar sua questão na própria *query*.

Supondo que você tenha uma tabela com as colunas `lat` e `lng` para as coordenadas e passando o seu ponto de referência (aqui vou usar como exemplo os valores *-19.83996* e *-43.94910*), basta fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT *, (6371 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(-19.83996)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(-43.94910) - radians(lng)) +
            sin(radians(-19.83996)) *
            sin(radians(lat))
        )) AS distance
FROM tabela HAVING distance <= 5
```

Com isso você vai obter todos os locais que estão à uma distância de **5 Km** do ponto de referência. Isto se encaixa na segunda opção que você informou, para buscar quais estão dentro do raio determinado.

Verifique se isto te atende da forma que deseja.

### Fórmula de Haversine

Entrando mais no detalhe da fórmula, ela é bem conhecida como [Fórmula de Haversine](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine), utilizada na navegação para calcular a distância entre dois pontos de uma esfera. Na solução é utilizada algumas funções matemática do próprio [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) como cálculo de **seno**, **cosseno**, **radiano** e etc, então pode ser facilmente transferida para outra tecnologia.

Aplicando essa fórmula à Terra, como é o seu caso, o resultado é apenas aproximado, já que a Terra não é uma esfera perfeita pois seu raio varia de 6356,78 km nos pólos até 6378,14 km no equador. Então, com essa variação, costuma utilizar o valor de **6371,00 Km** como o raio da Terra para este cálculo.

Comment: A consulta funcionou perfeitamente. Fiz uma consulta simulada, Paulo, onde incluí 3 pontos próximos do meu ponto central (o ponto de localização do usuário) e dois pontos mais distantes, a uma distancia de mais ou menos 4km. No filtro DISTANCIA na consulta informei 3 (3km) e como esperado ela retornou somente os pontos que estão dentro desse perímetro.

Comment: Uma última curiosidade onde encontrou esta fórmula? E qual o significado do número 6371 na consulta?

Comment: Esta fórmula costumo utilizar muito em meus aplicativos, já faz um tempo que tive essa necessidade e encontrei pela internet. Esse valor representa o valor aproximado do [raio terrestre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius), neste caso é de **6.371 Km**.

Comment: Paulo só para fechar o tópico com chave de ouro, só destaca na sua resposta a fórmula usada para calcular a distância. Indicando o que é cada coisa, por exemplo, o que é 6371. Seria algo assim: Fórmula para cálculo da distãncia: 
(RAIO_TERRESTRE * acos(cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * cos(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE)) * cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LONGITUDE) - radians(COLUNA_LONGITUDE)) + sin(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * sin(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE))).

Comment: Detalhei um pouco mais com base na *Wikipedia*.

Comment: Excelente resposta, +1.

Comment: Alguém poderia me dizer, quem sao as variaveis da consulta SQL na resposta acima? Sabendo que tem o ponto central de referencia, e o ponto de um usuario qualquer

Answer (score 3):

Mais ouro!!!

```
SELECT *,(RAIO_TERRESTRE * 
        acos(
         cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * 
         cos(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE)) * 
         cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LONGITUDE) - radians(COLUNA_LONGITUDE)) + 
         sin(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * 
         sin(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE))
      )) AS CAMPOLATITUDE
FROM TABELA HAVING CAMPOLATITUDE <= KM
```

Comment: Essa resposta já se [encontra aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55669/identificar-se-conjunto-de-coordenadas-est%c3%a1-dentro-de-um-raio-em-android/298823#comment114498_55710), e além disso eu não entendi nada da sua resposta. Poderia editar sua resposta e detalhar melhor???