# Localização de pontos específicos em mapas

Tags: java, geolocalização

Olá estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que trabalha com a biblioteca JXMapViewer na linguagem java, uma das propostas é encontrar pontos de geolocalização (ex: paradas/lanchonetes) em uma determinada rua que o usuário selecionar.

As informações de geolocalização dos pontos e a localização do usuário são informações já conhecidas. O problema é restringir a pesquisa para somente a rua onde o usuário selecionar utilizando a biblioteca. Não sei como verificar se o ponto está ou não na determinada rua.

Exemplo de geolocalização já fornecida:

```
GeoPosition ponto = new GeoPosition(ponto.getLatitude(), ponto.getLongitude());
```

[image: ponto vermelho o usuário e na rua selecionada os pontos verdes]

Alguém que já trabalhou com problemas parecidos ou similares poderia informar um exemplo?

Comment: Emanoel, isso talvez o ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55669/identificar-se-conjunto-de-coordenadas-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-um-raio-em-android

Comment: Olá @GeisonSantos já estou conseguindo pintar as geolocalização no mapa, meu problema maior é restringir os pontos em determinadas ruas..

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente falando aquilo que deverá fazer é em primeiro lugar fazer input na classe que indica, das coordenadas de localização geográfica do utilizador, devolvendo ao método as respectivas coordenadas longitudinais e de magnitude.
Isso pode ser feito através do tracking da posição do utilizador, ou, por exemplo através do uso de uma GUI (graphic user interface), para isso deverá seleccionar os pontos, e ter uma função que valide isso.

Para seleccionar a rua, deverá, muito sucintamente, seleccionar a variável de geolocalização da rua. e, ao fazer isso, criar uma função que seleccione a rua, se não for nessa biblioteca, haverá concerteza a possibilidade de encontrar um método ou uma classe externa para fazer isso. em ultima instancia, poderá implementar a classe de raiz. Espero poder ter sido útil.

Comment: Tiago, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Se der para [edit] a resposta e juntar exemplos seria excelenete.