# Consulta ao Banco de Dados em Android

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês para conferir o que está errado nessa consulta:

```
        int raioKm = 10;

        String latitude =
                "CONVERT("                                                          +
                    "NUMERIC(10,7), "                                               +
                    "SUBSTRING(localizacao, 0, CHARINDEX(localizacao, ',' - 1))"    +
                ")";
        String longitude =
                "CONVERT("                                                      +
                    "NUMERIC(10,7), "                                           +
                    "SUBSTRING(localizacao, CHARINDEX(localizacao, ',' + 1), "  +
                        "LEN(localizacao))"                                     +
                ")";

        String formulaHaversine = "(6371 * ACOS(" +
            "COS(radians("+ data.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.00) +")) * "      +
            "COS(radians(" + latitude + ")) * "                                 +
            "COS(radians("+ data.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.00) +") - "      +
            "RADIANS("+ longitude + ")) + "                                     +
            "SIN(radians(-19.83996)) * "                                        +
            "SIN(radians(" + latitude + "))"                                    +
        "))";

        System.out.println(latitude + ", " + longitude);

        String sql =    "SELECT idFoto as _id, localizacao, diretorio, descricao, "   +
            formulaHaversine + " AS distance FROM Foto HAVING distance <= " + raioKm;
```

**INTRODUÇÃO DO ASSUNTO**

Estou tentando trazer do banco de dados apenas as linhas da minha tabela que estão dentro de raio de 10 quilômetros a partir de um ponto de refêrência dado pela expressão *data.getDoubleExtra()* que retorna a latitude ou a longitude deste ponto.

A coluna *localizacao* da tabela Foto está formatada da seguinte forma: "latitude , longitude" (com os espaços antes e depois da vírgula) - e esta coluna que precisa ser reformatada para que os seus valores, do tipo *STRING*, possam ser convertidos para *DOUBLE*. Com esse objetivo, eu uso a função *CONVERT*, juntamente com outras funções, para obter a latitude e a longitude e assim utilizá-las na *STRING sql*.

Para determinar se as coordenadas estão dentro do raio determinado utiliza-se a Fórmula de Haversine ([Identificar se conjunto de coordenadas está dentro de um raio em Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55669/identificar-se-conjunto-de-coordenadas-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-um-raio-em-android)). Em seguida, a fórmula é utilizada para gerar a *STRING sql* "final".

**PROBLEMA**

Como eu já disse, este projeto é em **Android**. Por isso, essa consulta ao Banco de Dados está sendo feita dentro do método *onActivityResult* e quando eu tento compilá-la recebo o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   cmp=gborniam.bbphoto/.grafica.MapsActivity (has extras) }} to activity
>   {gborniam.bbphoto/gborniam.bbphoto.grafica.Principal}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: ACOS (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT idFoto as _id, localizacao, diretorio,
>   descricao, (6371 * ACOS(COS(radians(-17.478109860099323)) *
>   COS(radians(CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,7), SUBSTRING(localizacao, 0,
>   CHARINDEX(localizacao, ',' - 1))))) * COS(radians(-49.62723668664694)
>   - RADIANS(CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,7), SUBSTRING(localizacao, CHARINDEX(localizacao, ',' + 1), LEN(localizacao))))) +
>   SIN(radians(-19.83996)) * SIN(radians(CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,7),
>   SUBSTRING(localizacao, 0, CHARINDEX(localizacao, ',' - 1))))))) AS
>   distance FROM Foto HAVING distance <= 10

**SOS**

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo erro que está dando e pelo que [acabei de ler](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib), parece que o mesmo está ocorrendo porque o  SQLite não da suporte a função `ACOS`, além de outras que estão contidos na *query*.

Veja a parte mais relevante da exceção:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: ACOS (code
>   1):

Há um pequeno trecho [neste link](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib) que confirma a existência de outras alternativas criadas por usuários contribuintes da comunidade, porém são opções que não fazem parte do pacote padrão do SQLite, no qual deve ser usado por "*conta e rico do desenvolvedor*", afirmam, por não ter uma verificação oficial.

Veja alguns problemas similares abaixo:

- [Query to get records based on Radius in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite)
- [No such acos function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165073/no-such-acos-function-exists)
- [acos function in Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612538/acos-function-in-sqlite)

Uma sugestão talvez, digo talvez, mais viável para essa situação seria você usar a fórmula de Haversine no Java, para calcular a distância entre os ponto. Veja um [exemplo no Github](https://github.com/jasonwinn/haversine/blob/master/Haversine.java).

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado. Eu irei tentar implementar a fórmula utilizando a classe Math (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), assim eu já mando os valores calculados para a query.