# Comparar Latitude e Longitude em Python

Tags: android, python, coordenadas

Tenho uma aplicação onde um cliente Android manda as coordenadas para um servidor Python, que deve colocar tais informações em um Banco de Dados MySQL se o cliente estiver dentro de uma área (um polígono de 8 vértices, para ser exato), caso não esteja dentro da área, ele não coloca no banco de dados.

Só preciso saber como fazer essa comparação se o cliente está ou não dentro da área especificada, imagino que seja utilizando os valores de Latitude e Longitude.

Comment: Vamos entender..... O Android manda as coordenadas do ponto em que ele esta. Certo? E você quer saber se essa coordenada esta dentro de que limites mesmo?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55669/identificar-se-conjunto-de-coordenadas-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-um-raio-em-android?rq=1

Comment: @RodolfoDonato: Essa "área" se trata de um poligono irregular ? um circulo ?

Comment: Acabei esquecendo da forma da área. Um polígono irregular mesmo, de 8 vértices

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950062/checking-if-a-longitude-latitude-coordinate-resides-inside-a-complex-polygon-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca de manipulação de objetos no plano cartesiano chamada [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

def area_contem_cliente( a, c ):
    ponto = Point(c)
    poligono = Polygon(a)
    return poligono.contains(ponto)


cliente_brasilia = ( -15.7801, -47.9292 )
cliente_goiania = ( -16.6799, -49.255 )
cliente_paris = ( 48.85522811, 2.3493576 )
cliente_moscou = ( 55.75223582, 37.62182236 )


brasil = [ ( -8.046177, -34.584961 ),
         ( -20.784877, -40.737305 ),
         ( -33.713374, -53.481445 ),
         ( -30.285635, -57.612305 ),
         ( -16.370743, -60.249023 ),
         ( -7.436552, -73.696289 ),
         ( 4.403373, -64.907227 ),
         ( 4.228090, -51.547852 ) ]


print area_contem_cliente( brasil, cliente_brasilia )
print area_contem_cliente( brasil, cliente_goiania )
print area_contem_cliente( brasil, cliente_paris )
print area_contem_cliente( brasil, cliente_moscou )
```

Assumindo que um poligono de 8 vértices contorna o território Brasileiro no globo terrestre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída:

```
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: O servidor foi feito em Python3, então transferi esse código para o mesmo, só queria ressaltar que quando fui instalar a biblioteca para o Python 3.6, a mesma não oferece suporte, a versão mais recente suportada é a 3.5 do Python. Fica o alerta para os demais usuários. Melhor resposta impossível, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro substituir a área poligonal de 8 vértices por um círculo.

Você pode usar a [Fórmula de Haversine](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine) para calcular a distancia entre duas coordenadas geográficas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Uma vez com a distância entre o cliente e o ponto de referência calculada, você é capaz de avaliar se o cliente está dentro do "raio" da area especificada.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

# Formula de Haversine
def haversine( a, b ):
    # Raio da Terra em Km
    r = 6371

    # Converte coordenadas de graus para radianos
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [ a['longitude'], a['latitude'], b['longitude'], b['latitude'] ] )

    # Formula de Haversine
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    hav = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    d = 2 * r * asin( sqrt(hav) )

    return d


brasilia = {'latitude': -15.7801, 'longitude': -47.9292 }
goiania = {'latitude': -16.6799, 'longitude': -49.255}
paris = {'latitude': 48.85522811, 'longitude': 2.3493576 }
moscou = {'latitude': 55.75223582, 'longitude': 37.62182236 }

print "Brasilia-DF x Goiania-GO: " + str( haversine( brasilia, goiania) ) + " Km"
print "Brasilia-DF x Paris-Franca: " + str( haversine( brasilia, paris ) ) + " Km"
print "Moscou-Russia x Paris-Franca: " + str( haversine( moscou, paris ) ) + " Km"
print "Goiania-GO x Moscou-Russia: " + str( haversine( goiania, moscou ) ) + " Km"
```

Saída:

```
Brasilia-DF x Goiania-GO: 173.336761581 Km
Brasilia-DF x Paris-Franca: 8725.7318322 Km
Moscou-Russia x Paris-Franca: 2486.76670169 Km
Goiania-GO x Moscou-Russia: 11341.7186759 Km
```